# Book geometry with margins and binding offset

Tags: geometry

The mwe given below illustrates my current settings in the book am working. Unfortunately I find it a bit cumbersome and outdated although it achieves what I want it to do. One of my objectives is to have both even and odd pages have the margin on the left side; this has been done. My issue is that I don't think the spacing are the same for both pages. For example, for page 2, the binding is on the right and on 3 it is on the left and `showframe` does not show the margin paragraph section.

What I want is that all lengths are accounted for and that both pages are technically the same. I feel like I am forcing the geometry to look like what I want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[
    letterpaper,
    bindingoffset=0.2in,
    centering,
    marginparwidth=2in,
    textwidth=5.1in,
    marginparsep=2em,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    showframe
]{geometry} 
\evensidemargin 1.5in
\oddsidemargin 2in 

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
\reversemarginpar
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve and the [link](https://books.google.com.bz/books?id=OzvEe6TnonoC&pg=PR8&lpg=PR8&dq=trigonometry%209th%20edition%20ron%20larson%20view%20sample&source=bl&ots=lHMEQovjuJ&sig=6JP470m5C5rweKLzFx2ovPj8MN8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiExIWpwrXNAhWOix4KHbNdAo4Q6AEIRzAI#v=onepage&q&f=false) to the sample.

[image]

The image below gives an overview of the layout I am seeking to achieve.

[image]

Comment: What about  **oneside** option? i.e.,  `\documentclass[11pt, oneside,openany]{book}` ?

Answer (score 2):

The different values for `\evensidemargin` and `\oddsidemargin` seem questionable to me if you're trying to have a two-sided document have exactly the same off-centred layout.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'margin paragraph section', but if you mean you want the `\marginpar`s to end up always on the left-hand side of both the recto and verso pages, then maybe the following works. (`\marginpar`s can be frustrating to work with.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[
    letterpaper,
    bindingoffset=0.2in,
    centering,
    marginparwidth=2in,
    textwidth=5.1in,
    marginparsep=2em,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    showframe
]{geometry}
\evensidemargin 1.5in
\oddsidemargin 1.5in

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
%\reversemarginpar
\makeatother

\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\newcommand\mmp[1]{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
   \reversemarginpar
   \marginpar[#1]{}
  \else
   \normalmarginpar
   \marginpar{#1}
  \fi
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\mmp{Odd, left-hand side}
\lipsum[1-6]
\mmp{Even, left-hand side}
\lipsum[7-12]
\mmp{Odd again, left-hand side}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See the updated layout. By the way, thanks for attempting to address my issue but your answer is not what I am looking for. I am looking for symmetry in terms of my layout and that each section is properly spaced accordingly.

Comment: @azetina -- The picture helps, though I cannot understand what 'symmetry' you mean since the pages are not symmetrical. In fact, it would be far easier to implement (I think) the page layout if the binding offset and the actual margins (beyond the `marginpar` area) were the same width.

Answer (score 2):

[image: mwe]

Using `geometry` you only need a **oneside** document and set  `lmargin`, `rmargin`, `marginparwidth` and `marginparsep` options. Of course, enabling `\reversemarginpar` if you want margin notes in the right (left) margin.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=8cm,rmargin=1cm,marginparwidth=6cm,marginparsep=2em]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum,sidenotes,tabularx}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\sidenote{A side note text} 
\lipsum[5]
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Some image}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[2-5]
\begin{margintable}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|XXXXXX|}
\hline
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26\\
    31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36\\
    41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46\\
    51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some table}    
\end{margintable}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

BTW: Taking into account the layout, consider use the `tufte-book` document class.

Comment: I learnt something new from your code but are you including the binding offset setting?

Comment: @azetina I guess that you can add the  `bindingoffset`  and reduce the `lmargin` accordingly, if that matter in one side document.